# Is there a lower bound on the std deviation for v.kernel in GRASS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, heat-map, kernel-density

I'm using the v.kernel function in GRASS to create heat maps. I am able to generate an acceptable heat map using a std deviation of .2 and a several thousand rows and columns. After the map is generated, I look at it in QGIS.

```
v.kernel input=data output=heatmap stddeviation=.2
```

However, if I go to a std deviation below .2, all I get is a black rectangle. A std dev of .19 or .1 or .01 results in no variation being shown on the heat map, just all black. Does anyone know why this might be? I want to be able to increase the granularity and precision of the maps I'm creating, and lowering the stddeviation would seem to be the solution.

Comment: what is your map unit and the distance between closest points ?

Comment: At the module manual, https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.kernel.html, there is a -q flag whose function is only calculate optimal standard deviation and exit (no map is written).

Comment: @radouxju the map unit is in degrees. As far as the closest points, I am not sure, but there are hundreds of thousands of points and there are bound to points practically on top of one another as these are IP addresses for every AS in the United States that I am mapping.

Comment: @xunilk I tried that option but due to the enormous amount of data, I ran into an error where GRASS cannot allocate enough memory in order to calculate this optimum std dev.

Comment: have you tried epanechnikov instead of gaussian (the default), so that you don't look too far ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I checked the documentation and it shows that you can change between different kernel types. I can look up the differences myself: do you mean I should try it in the context of xunilk's comment or your comment?